# php array con corchetes

Tags: php, php7

hola tengo que mostrar en un array tres datos usando un array con corchetes

```
$lenguajesp = ["java" , "c#" , "php"];

echo "Lenguajes de programacion: ". 
     $lenguajesp[0].$lenguajesp[1].$lenguajesp[2];
```

pero me salta este error y no logro solucionarlo alguien me puede ayudar?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$lenguajesp' (T_VARIABLE),
>
> ### > expecting ',' or ';'

codigo competo:

```
<?php 
//Ejercicio1
$nombre = "Agustin Hernandez";
$edad = "19 años";
$carrera = "Ingenieria en Sistemas";
$cuota ="";

echo "Mi nombre es: ", $nombre, " Mi edad es: ",$edad," Yo estudio la carrera de: ",$carrera," y pago: ", $cuota,"<br>";
//Ejercicio 2
echo "Mi nombre es:  $nombre,  Mi edad es: $edad, Yo estudio la carrera de: $carrera y pago:  \$$cuota <br>";
//Ejercicio 3
$ej3= array("Pedro","Pepe","Juan");
var_dump($ej3);
echo "<br>";
echo $ej3[0]." ";
echo $ej3[2]." ";
echo $ej3[1]." ";
echo "<br>";
//Ejercicio 4
$estudiantes= array('1' =>'Pepe','2'=>'juan','3'=>'sofia','4'=>'pedro','5'=>'esteban','6'=>'mario');
echo "Estudiantes de Ingenieria: "." ". $estudiantes[1]." ". $estudiantes[3]." ". $estudiantes[5], " Estudiantes de Tecnico: ". $estudiantes[2]." ". $estudiantes[4]." ". $estudiantes[6]
//Ejercicio 5
$lenguajesp = ["java" , "c#" , "php"];
echo "Lenguajes de programacion: ". $lenguajesp[0].$lenguajesp[1].$lenguajesp[2]

 ?>
```

Comment: listo el error hace referencia a la linea 23(la variable de lenguajes)

Comment: te hace falta un `;` en el echo después del primer array casi al final de tu código

Comment: y también en el último echo de todo tu código ahi también te falta un `;`

Comment: ¿Tu código es de algún curso o ejercicio? Pregunto porque se podría optimizar y simplificar.

Comment: si , si lo es..

Answer (score 2):

Te faltó el `;` final en las líneas 20 y 23 (al final del todo). Lo correcto sería:

```
<?php

// ....

//Ejercicio 4
$estudiantes= array('1' =>'Pepe','2'=>'juan','3'=>'sofia','4'=>'pedro','5'=>'esteban','6'=>'mario');
echo "Estudiantes de Ingenieria: "." ". $estudiantes[1]." ". $estudiantes[3]." ". $estudiantes[5], " Estudiantes de Tecnico: ". $estudiantes[2]." ". $estudiantes[4]." ". $estudiantes[6]; //Aquí te falto el ; que lo eh puesto

//Ejercicio 5
$lenguajesp = ["java" , "c#" , "php"];
echo "Lenguajes de programacion: ". $lenguajesp[0].$lenguajesp[1].$lenguajesp[2]; //Aquí te faltó el ; que lo he puesto.
?>
```

Comment: @fedorqui muchas gracias por tu ayuda, te lo agradezco mucho.